# iOS Swift Master > Master > Detail?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, master-detail

I'm trying to get my head around the logic here, apologies if the terminology is not correct.

Im trying to build an app that functions loosely like mail does, IE:

All MailBoxes > Specific Mail Box > Messages

Where 'All Mailboxes' and 'Specific Mail Box' occupy the Master View of the controller, while 'Messages' occupies the Detail View of the controller.

If I download and look at the xCode example of Master-Detail it gives me a Single master and a single detail setup, how do I attached a 'pre' master page and a second 'detail' page to this so that it goes:

MasterView0 > MasterView1 > DetailView0 > DetailView1 ?

Do you extend the navigation controller in Storyboard or is it better to start with lots of single views and stitch them together?

Thanks
Mathew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've done this in the past is to create each view as a separate View Controller in the storyboard. In the two "Master" views, I had a table with one Prototype Cell that I used to create the segue path.

You can embed these into a navigation controller, as well, which would allow you to unwind your segues a bit more naturally.